# Can't run Docker Containerised Dash App after Docker update

Tags: docker, plotly-dash

I've built a Dash app I'd like to run locally by way of a Docker container. I've cloned the repo, done `docker build` on the resulting directory and now it's running in a docker container.

The problem is that docker prompted me to update, and being a good little soldier I did. However, after the update there no longer seems to be an option to launch the app in my browser. I don't have access to the old version of docker I was using, but the button used to be adjacent to the ones on the screenshot.

Does anyone know what the issue might be here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You've got a problem with the ports. Unfortunately, you took the screenshot when the container stopped running. If its status is "Running", you should see the port on which you can access it.